# modify columns according to condition

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, conditional-statements

Well I have the following problem, I have 2 columns as follows:

```
 A B
"X" 1
"Y" 1
"Z" 0
"W" 2
```

What I want to do is find a way to create new columns C and D or better still, update columns A and B as follows:

```
 C D
"X" 1
"Y" 1
"Z" 0
"W (1)" 1
"W (2)" 1
```

Any suggestion or ideas on how can i do this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supposed to be a code writing forum. You are expected to show some effort.

```
Sub split_()

Dim P1 As Range
Range("C1:D99999").Clear
Set P1 = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
a = 1

For i = P1(1).Row To P1.Rows.Count
    If P1(i, 2) > 1 Then
        For j = 1 To P1(i, 2)
            Cells(a, 3) = P1(i, 1) & " (" & j & ")"
            Cells(a, 4) = 1
            a = a + 1
        Next j
    Else
        Cells(a, 3) = P1(i, 1)
        Cells(a, 4) = P1(i, 2)
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot